# How do you style or override the default hover color for drop down menus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I know, someway, somehow, you can do this. I just am not sure. I would preferably like to override the default blue hover for select menus (drop downs) so that I can add a box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 3px to my options.

So, JavaScript, JQuery, (preferably) CSS?

I don't know much about JavaScrip and JQuery... I haven't gotten that far yet, but any help with this problem would be *greatly* appreciated.

Thank you!

http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab6/level-1/

Comment: I don't think you can change the hover colour of the option elements of the select element. You could maybe look at using a UL instead and styling the LI elements as you like.

Comment: @BillyMoat: You should post that as an answer and add a small code sample. I'd tap that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every browser allows that. in fact, If you look at your website in chrome, you'll see that the selectbox itself is not even displaying the grey background. Resulting in white text on a white background.
If you really want to style the dropdown yourself, I would suggest to use javascript/jquery to replace the select/option with an ul/li, which you can style as you wish.

I'll try to find some examples to get you started. Just a second.

Edit: This should get you started: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/better-select-jquery-css3/

edit2: here's another one: http://bnotions.com/form-select-replacement-using-jquery-css/

And this person even created a plugin: http://forrst.com/posts/jQuery_plugin_ReplaceDropdown_to_replace_a_selec-NA2

disclaimer: I haven't tested any of the links above myself. So use at your own discretion.

Comment: Works in FF but not in Chrome for me - Did you get that the wrong way around?

Comment: I'm sorry. yeah, that's what I ment to say. Fine in firefox, white on white in chrome

Comment: It's not styled for Chrome. For this purpose, I only need to style it for Firefox.

Comment: http://bnotions.com/form-select-replacement-using-jquery-css/ This tutorial is really nice! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that the properties for the drop box are in line #103 through #114. Please explain your answer more fully, as in the box BORDER itself or the text and you want NOTHING behind it?

Answer (score 0):

use unbind() function of jquery to unbind hover then try binding again by .css() you should be able to chang