# dropdown under a nav button css/html

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

I have a navcontainer with buttons in the container. I need to make a dropdown list for only one of the buttons. How would this be accomplished with CSS/HTML. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="navcontainer">
            <a href="/home.html" class="button" style="width: 115px">About Us</a>
            <a href="/quote.html" class="button" style="width: 170px">Request a Quote</a>
            <a href="/affiliates.html" class="button" style="width: 115px">Affiliates</a>
            <a href="/pricing.html" class="button" style="width: 170px">Pricing & Plans</a>
            <a href="/addservices.html" class="button" style="width: 190px">Additional Services</a>
            <a href="/service.html" class="button" style="width: 165px">Service Details</a>
            <a href="/watering.html" class="button" style="width: 108px">Watering</a>
           </div>
```

CSS:

```
#navcontainer {
 float: right;
 width: 1040px;
 height: 45px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 45px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 6px;
```

}

```
.button {
text-align: center;
background: #226426;
color: #fff;
width: 100px;
height: 45px;
float: left;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
border-right: solid 1px #91b293;
border-top: solid 1px #91b293;
border-bottom: solid 1px #91b293;
```

}

Do I need to make this into a ul or can I keep it as is, and just add a dropdown to the Services button?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If i understand correctly: the user sees all these buttons, when hovering over 1 specific button, a dropdown list will roll out of that button? If so, take a look this. Let me know if this doesn't help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857915/how-do-you-style-or-override-the-default-hover-color-for-drop-down-menus/12858015#12858015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, it's always a good idea to have your navigation in a list, it helps keep your options open to a multidimensional menu system at any point. Here is what I would do:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="link1.html">link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="link2.html">link 2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="sublink1.html">sublink 1</a></li>
<li><a href="sublink2.html">sublink 2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="link3.html">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav, #nav ul {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#nav li {position: relative;}
#nav li ul {position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; display: none;}
#nav li:hover ul {display: block;}
```

**jQuery - optional**

This is if you wanted some sort of effect on the

```
function mainmenu(){
$(" #nav ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
$(" #nav li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display:     none"}).show(800);
    },function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.